# CPQ Contracted Price at Contract level

Tags: cpq

In CPQ I get that a Contracted Price can be given to a particular Account/Product.  However, if that Account were to create a Contract which contained let's say 3 products, is there a way that I can set it such that if that Contract is renewed, the same price is applied?

The way I see it is that in the above scenario, each of the 3 products would be created as a Contracted Price record on the Account, so if the Contract was renewed, the price would correctly be applied.

BUT, if the Account were to order 1 of the 3 products, the same reduced price would used where we would like the full price to be used instead.

I'm new to CPQ, so any pointers would be very useful.  Thanks.